# How to drive a RAON tech RDP502H module?

Tags: augmented-reality, open-source

I'm trying to use a display module to do some cool things (my own AR glasses).
But obviously, I've encountered some difficulties. I managed to acquire a display module from a mature solution, but I'm not sure how to use them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vKg.jpg)
This is what it and its controller look like, unfortunately, this is one of their products, and I can't start this controller.

The most critical part of this controller is called RDC200A. I have tried to obtain its communication protocol to simulate these signals using other methods, but I am unsure how to proceed.

I learned that they used to have a suite called RDC200A VEB Tool, but I can't find any information about these solutions now.
Here is their product page:

http://www.raon-tech.com/microdisplay/products.php

I'm trying to use ChatGPT to search for relevant information, but it clearly can't provide highly specialized knowledge.

I do get something, but it seems not what i mean:
https://www.semiee.com/b5e8f5b5-5ac2-4232-9a15-eb7ae79c2595.html

I'm sure it's using LVDS signal, but it seems not a common one.

Perhaps using a logic analyzer could be a possible direction? However, I lack the relevant experience and skills.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me how to get started.